# qTreeView scrollToBottom() ignored

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

Overflowers!

I'm getting crazy trying using scrollTo() in qTreeView (or QListView) widget. To make my question simple I've reduced my code to a simple scrollToBottom() which I can't manage to use as well. Here is the mainWindow code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <qfilesystemmodel.h>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    QModelIndex modelRootIndex = model->setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());
    ui->treeView->setModel(model);
    ui->treeView->setRootIndex(modelRootIndex);
    ui->treeView->scrollToBottom();
    if(modelRootIndex.isValid()) std::cout << "validIndex" << std::endl;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

As far as I know it's all ok (I get the "ValidIndex" string on standard output), but the widget doesn't scroll to bottom at all.

I'm using Desktop  QT5.0.2 msvc2010 32bit.

Any Idea? Thanks. L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QFileSystemModel` and the `QFileSystemWatcher` are kept up-to-date in a separate thread. Thus, simply setting the model on the tree view does not ensure that the model will be fully populated by the time you make the call to `scrollToBottom`. Use a single shot timer with a small delay to give the model time to populate.

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000, ui->treeView, SLOT(scrollToBottom()));
```

Additionally, (and I don't know your application, so this may or may not be true) it *may* be confusing to your users that the data they need to see is at the bottom of the view anyway. You may think about whether you can sort the view items in reverse order (thus having the data you need at the top) to avoid scrolling and potentially make the usage more intuitive.

Comment: Nicolas, thanks. Problem solved. The code I wrote here was in fact a toy problem whose target was to analyze my real problem which was related to a scrollTo(...) method. On the base of your hint this other problem has been solved. Thanks again. L

Comment: If this answer helped, feel free to upvote it or mark it as the answer. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Nicolas, I was able to accept your answer (same as mark it as the answer?) but not to mark it as useful as it needs 15 reputations... Did I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the asynchronous way that `QFileSystemModel` works, and what appears to be a bug in Qt that was never fixed: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9326

You can work around it by doing `QApplication::sendPostedEvents()` immediately before the call to `scrollTo()`, but you must call them in a function that is connected to the `directoryLoaded` signal:

```cpp
MyFileBrowser::MyFileBrowser(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::MyFileBrowser) {
  //...
  connect(model, SIGNAL(directoryLoaded(QString)), this, SLOT(dirLoaded(QString)));
  QModelIndex folderIndex = model->index("path/to/dir");
  files->setCurrentIndex(folderIndex);
  files->expand(folderIndex);
}

void WFileBrowser::dirLoaded(QString dir) {
    if (dir == model->filePath(files->currentIndex())) {
        QApplication::sendPostedEvents(); // booyah!!
        files->scrollTo(files->currentIndex(), QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop);
    }
}
```